# Which algorithm for **DOCUMENT SIMILARITY** is reasonable for calculating on local machine?

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I would like to do **DOCUMENT SIMILARITY** about 3000 times at a program running.

I tried it with the algorithm of **[BERT-sore](https://github.com/Tiiiger/bert_score)**. However, this algorithm is too heavy to finish the program running.

So I have a question.

- BERT another algorithm
- Doc2vec
- USE
- other algorithm

Which is the lightest algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the TF-IDF to compare documents, it's pretty lightweight, and start there.